# OSRM gives negative driving distance, why?

Tags: osrm

With this query, the result is -0.3 meters driving distance. Is there some reason why the result is negative? The points are by a one-way street, if that matters.

https://router.project-osrm.org/table/v1/default/34.767694,32.064663;34.767696,32.064674?sources=0&destinations=1&annotations=distance&skip_waypoints=true